# MYSQL: Join two tables on one field or another depending on a condition

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to join two tables on one field or another, depending on the values of those fields.

Here is my situation, I have a friends Database with User IDs in two columns. For example:

```
uid1    uid2
------- -------
tom001  bob001
bob001  paul001
```

In this example `bob001` is friends with both `tom001` and `paul001` (and vice versa).

Now I am trying to get a list of friends for a certain user and then join that with the Users Database, so I can get at the users name, picture, etc.

My question is, how can I join two tables using a value that could be in `uid1` or `uid2` but not both? In this example, if I wanted to show `bob001`'s friends, I would have to join the two tables first on the value in `uid1` and then on the value in `uid2`.

Is there a way in SQL to ignore one of these User IDs and use the other? Can I somehow merge the values of these fields together, stripping out the original User ID?

Or can I use an `IF` statement to get at the correct User ID?

TIA

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: I was hoping to get a more generalized answer, rather than a specific answer to my exact SQL problem. I don't necessarily need the answer spoon feeding to me, but I would love to be pointed in the right direction - I am happy to learn. Surely more generalized knowledge of these kinds of problems would be of greater benefit to others on Stack Overflow anyway?

Comment: The clearest questions tend to attract the clearest answers.

Comment: Is my question not clear? Or are you trying to say that only questions that provide SQLFiddles and/or copypasta code are clear questions? All I want to know is if joining two tables on a field that is chosen by a conditional is possible, and if it is, what approach I should use. Ironically I only gave an example of my specific situation to add clarity to my question.

Comment: I'm saying that the clearest questions tend to be those that provide result sets that conform to respective data sets. But do whatever makes you happy. That said, note that one reason frequently given for closing questions on SO is that they are 'too broad'

Comment: @Jimmery if any of these solutions was what you need please mark it as solved.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, here is the MYSQL query. Just to make the MYSQL easier to follow create the following view.

```
 create view allfriends as select uid1,uid2 from tablename 
 union select uid2,uid1 from tablename;
```

Then this select

```
 select uid2 from allfriends where uid1 = 'bob001';
```